# Remote control of DC motor

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, remote-control

This is PWM controller I bought for speed control of DC motor:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/6-30V-DC-Motor-speed-Controller-Reversible-PWM-Control-Forward-Reverse-Switch-/162002954574?hash=item25b820e94e:g:RAMAAOSw6EhUQgOp

DC motor rotation direction is controlled using switch: when switch is in position I motor rotates in one direction and when it is in position II motor rotates in opposite direction.
Since I need to have limiters also, I removed this switch and shorted controller on this way:

[image: fig1]

Instead of only motor, I put on output of controller DPDT switch, limiters and motor. It looks like this:

[image: fig2]

Here is schematic:

[image: fig3]

Now I can change direction of rotation using DPDT, I have also limiters and of course I can control speed.
My question is, is it possible to remotely control direction of rotation instead of manual control using DPDT?

Comment: To electronically control a switch, you typically need to know something about the nature of the circuit it is in, particularly for a non-isolated switch made of semiconductors.  If you do not know that and cannot deduce it, your options are more limited.  A relay whose ratings include the maximum possibility is one way.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a DPDT relay, or you can use a different kind of speed controller that uses a "dual H-bridge" where it controls BOTH speed and direction using four transistors.